# Converting long int to string in PHP

Tags: php, flash-media-server

I'm using FMS along with PHP and I need the client's ID in order to disconnect some user at some point. So, I retrieve client's ID from FMS, but FMS sends the ID as a long int, such as `4702111234508538223`.

Here's my problem; I need to convert this number to something like `oAACAAAA` in PHP. Is there any short way or some kind of library exists to doing this? Otherwise I have to convert [this AS3 library](http://code.google.com/p/lodgamebox/source/browse/trunk/com/lordofduct/util/LongInt.as)  into PHP.

Comment: @Jared You wouldn't happen to know how PHP stores it's integer types internally would you?

Comment: @JamWaffles - Sorry, can't talk; foot's in mouth. My thought was there's no way there wasn't already a solution for this, but I'm finding something different seems to be the case.

Comment: I see that the problem is Adobe has bricks between their ears. How did *they* get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function converts something like `"4702111234525315439"` into something like `"oAADAAAA"`:

```
function convert_id_to_str($id)
{
   if (strspn($id, '0123456789') != strlen($id)) {
      return false;
   }
   $str = '';
   if (PHP_INT_SIZE >= 8) {
      while ($id) {
         $str .= chr($id & 255);
         $id >>= 8;
      }
   } else {
      while ($id) {
         $str .= chr(bcmod($id, '256'));
         $id   =     bcdiv($id, '256', 0);
      }
   }
   return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use either [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) PHP functionalities to be sure to handle 64-bit number on 32 and 64-bit PHP capable server, and then [`pack`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) the result in a formatted string, e.g. :

```
$id = "4702111234508538223";

$hi = bcdiv($id, pow(2, 32));
$lo = bcsub($id, bcmul($hi, pow(2, 32)));

var_dump(pack("LL", $lo, $hi));
```

Returns `string(8) "oAACAAAA"`.
The code is *exploded* but could easily be turned to a one-liner or function as well. The use of a big number extension ensure compatibility with 32-bits platforms but if you're sure the platform hosting your PHP interpreter have 64-bit capabilities you could just use

```
pack("LL", $id, $id / pow(2, 32));
```